# How to compare 2 Lists in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, linq, dictionary

I have Database model

```
public class Dish
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Ingridient, int> Ingridients { get; set; }
        public List<String> Images { get; set; }
        public String  Guide { get; set; }
        public Guid User { get; set; }
        public DishType dishType { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }

        public enum DishType
        {
            Polish,
            Asian,
            Indian,
            Other
        };
    }
```

I'd like to get all dishes that have ingridients that are asked of from `List<Ingridient>`. Something like

Input `List<Ingridient>`

Get all Dishes where Dictionary containts all these ingridients. While Ingridient is Key.

I tried some slow solution that worked on all dishes from database but I'd like to move to query Database to make it faster.

My Solution - very slow and takes a lot of memory:

```
List<Dish> allDishes = Dishes.Select(n => n).ToList();
            List<Dish> Found = new List<Dish>();
            foreach(var d in allDishes)
            {
                List<Ingridient> fromDish = d.Ingridients.Keys.ToList();

                foreach(var ing in ingridients)
                {
                    if (!fromDish.Contains(ing))
                        break;
                }

                Found.Add(d);
            }
```

I'd like to recreate this behaviour as Linq query.

Comment: I've tried searching for a solution but I didn't find anything helpful yet. I tried to come up with my own Linq but to be honest it's too complicated for me.

Comment: I've edited my question. If there is somthing missing or something is wrong I'd be grateful for your help in fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dishes.Where(dish => !ingredients.Except(dish.Ingredients).Any()).ToList();
```

Where `!ingredients.Except(dish.Ingredients).Any()` checks that all ingredients in the request list are contained in the ingredients of the dish.

You can fiddle with fiddle with a test [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vWYeue).

Comment: Thank you, I've tried a couple of my own linqs but I couldn't get the result. Also I don't know what I did wrong in     `var foundDishes = Dishes.Where(dish => dish.Ingridients.Keys.ToList().Exists(ing => ingridients.Contains(ing))).ToList();`